# More efficient script?

Tags: linux, bash

I just threw together a quartet of Raspberry Pi 3's as a dedicated BOINC cluster. I like what I've got, but monitoring progress is a little meh since my main desktop environment is Linux (Windows has good GUI's with remote monitoring support, but the Linux equivalents appear to be defunct).

Anyway, I threw together this bash script to keep track of things

```
#!/bin/bash

tasks=($(boinccmd --get_tasks | grep ')' | cut -d ')' -f1))
progress=($(boinccmd --get_tasks | grep fraction | awk '{ print $NF }'))
remaining=($(boinccmd --get_tasks | grep remaining | awk '{ print $NF }'))

tabs -4 &> /dev/null

echo "${tasks[-1]} task(s)"

for i in "${tasks[@]}"; do
  if [ $(echo "${progress[((--i))]} > 0.000" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
    progress_as_percent=$(echo "scale=1; (${progress[((--i))]}*100)/1" | /usr/bin/bc)
    remaining_as_hours=$(echo "scale=0; ${remaining[((--i))]}/3600" | /usr/bin/bc)
    remaining_as_minutes=$(echo "scale=0; (${remaining[((--i))]}/60)-(${remaining_as_hours}*60)" | /usr/bin/bc)
    echo -e "#$i"'\t'"${progress_as_percent}%"'\t'"${remaining_as_hours}:${remaining_as_minutes}"
  fi
done

cpu_temp="$(sudo cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)"
cpu_temp=$(echo "scale=1; ${cpu_temp}/1000" | bc)

core0freq="$(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq)"
core0freq=$(echo "scale=2; ${core0freq}/1000000" | bc)
core1freq="$(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq)"
core1freq=$(echo "scale=2; ${core1freq}/1000000" | bc)
core2freq="$(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq)"
core2freq=$(echo "scale=2; ${core2freq}/1000000" | bc)
core3freq="$(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq)"
core3freq=$(echo "scale=2; ${core3freq}/1000000" | bc)

tabs -8 &> /dev/null

echo
echo "${core0freq}/${core1freq}/${core2freq}/${core3freq}GHz ${cpu_temp}'C"
```

And the output looks about like this:

```
12 task(s)
#1      33.3%   11:14
#3      29.2%   12:50
#6      31.4%   12:15
#10     31.6%   11:58

1.20/1.20/1.20/1.20GHz  46.6'C
```

I have no idea the efficiency of `bc` vs other alternatives, nor the many shells I'm sure this script instantiates. Obviously, since the RPi3 is such an underpowered machine when it comes to FLOPS per dollar, this build isn't principally concerned with efficiency... but none the less! I want to know what I could do to lean up getting the information I'm after. Keeping track of the workload isn't really all that important, but the CPU temperatures and core clocks are.

Thanks in advance. =)

EDIT: per request, here's what `boinccmd --get_tasks` looks like:

```
pi@serverpi:~ $ boinccmd --get_tasks

======== Tasks ========
1) -----------
   name: p2030.20151124.G196.37-01.56.N.b3s0g0.00000_1563_1
   WU name: p2030.20151124.G196.37-01.56.N.b3s0g0.00000_1563
   project URL: http://einstein.phys.uwm.edu/
   report deadline: Sat Sep 17 01:19:42 2016
   ready to report: no
   got server ack: no
   final CPU time: 28977.680000
   state: downloaded
   scheduler state: preempted
   exit_status: 0
   signal: 0
   suspended via GUI: no
   active_task_state: UNINITIALIZED
   app version num: 142
   checkpoint CPU time: 28917.330000
   current CPU time: 28977.680000
   fraction done: 0.502852
   swap size: 127 MB
   working set size: 125 MB
   estimated CPU time remaining: 28691.772814
```

And on for (in my case) 14 separate work units.

Comment: Maybe you could show typical output of `boinccmd --get_tasks`?

Comment: Added the output. =)

Comment: This entire mess looks like it wants to be refactored into a single Awk script.

Comment: You say mess, I say learning. Way to bring the knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to invoke `boinccmd` three times at the start and then invoke `bc` three times for each task. So, for 14 tasks, you would have 45 processes, whereas you could just invoke `boinccmd` once and `awk` once and get much the same.

I don't have forever to do it all for you, but it could look as simple as this:

```
boinccmd --get_tasks | awk -F '[):]' '
   /^[0-9])/   {tasks++}
   /fraction/  {pctdone=$2*100}
   /remaining/ {hrs=int($2/3600)
                mins=int(($2-(hrs*3600))/60)
                printf "#%d\t%2.1f\t%d:%02d\n",tasks,pctdone,hrs,mins}
   END{printf "%d task(s)\n",tasks}
   '
```

**Output**

```
#1  50.3    7:58
#2  98.0    1:00
2 task(s)
```

I added in a bit more logic and improved the numbering, so it now looks like this:

```
./boinccmd --get_tasks | awk -F '[):]' '
   /^[0-9])/        { tasks++; thisTask=$1; p=1 }
   /fraction/       { pctdone=$2*100; if(pctdone<0.001)p=0 }
   /remaining/ && p { hrs=int($2/3600); mins=int(($2-(hrs*3600))/60)
                      printf "#%d\t%2.1f\t%d:%02d\n",thisTask,pctdone,hrs,mins}
   END{printf "%d task(s)\n",tasks}'
```

Comment: Thank you very kindly for taking the time you chose to illustrate the possibilities. I've never used `awk` for more than printing out fields, so I've got some reading to do. =)